# Rubber tracks for robots

Tags: robotics

I have to manufacture a tracked robot weighing nearly 40 Kg's and the operation is mostly on rusted metal surface.

I will be using 2 rubber(1 in*30 in)tracks for movement but I'm worried it will wear sooner than tires has anyone worked on this, so that I know how long I can operate the robot until the tire completely wears.

Comment: Ratio of turns to straight lines... Tracks are chosen for various reasons, what did you consider?

Comment: Why do you needs tracks if you are traveling on rusted metal? That's like using snow shoes on solid ground. Tracks are meant for heavy loads on soft surfaces. If you only need to climbing obstacles or traction, that can be done with creative wheel arrangements. This sounds like a misapplication of tracks to me.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "rubber".

Comment: 1" wide tracks is also way too thin for 40kg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These factors come to mind more prominantly

- The rusty surface could have chemicals that change the rubber and make it brittle and thus shorten its life.
- The track has to be tight and not too wide to give it manouverability and proprtioned not to lag behind the wheels due to its inertia and cuase spining of the wheel
- The tracks have to be rather short and have small indentations and be chamfered at the edges to promote flexibilty and traction and turn on command.

Comment: thanks!! I can proceed with the information

Answer (score 0):

A lot  of factors can affect the life of tracks  (and tires). E.g.

- maximum straight line acceleration (the higher the acceleration, the maximum the tire force, therefore)
- the combination of turning ratio and speed (close turns at the same speed will
- geometry of the tracks (i.e. the ratio of width between tracks to the length of each track).
- roughness of the surface
- UV radiation and other enivonmental condition: (the higher the UV radiation the faster the degradation of the rubber tires).
- ... (probably a lot more are there)

The point is that its very difficult to calculate in advance the wear out of a tire without knowing the exact specifics of the operation, environment and model of tire.

Comment: ok
however i find your comment very useful and will use those considerations to estimate the wear